# How to combine outputs of ps and lsof

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, shell-scripting

Usually output of `ps` has a pid somewhere. Is there a way to combine this, preferably with a one-liner, with an output of `lsof` ?

e.g.

```
27915 ?        Ss     0:03 gpg-agent --daemon
gpg-agent 27915      httpd  mem     REG      104,1    144776     229236 /lib64/ld-2.5.so
gpg-agent 27915      httpd  mem     REG      104,1   1718232     229237 /lib64/libc-2.5.so
gpg-agent 27915      httpd  mem     REG      104,1     23360     229238 /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
...

6139 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/restorecond
restoreco 6139 root  mem    REG  104,1    53880 228954 /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
restoreco 6139 root    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0   1771 /dev/null
...
```

Note: the first block's first line is output of `ps` for pid `27915` followed by output `lsof -p 27915`; the second block is same for pid `6139`.

Essentially I would like a join by pid between two commands but output line(s) of first command first and then output lines of second command with same pid. The output is not the same as running something like `join -1 2 -2 2 <(ps aux | sort -nk2) <(lsof | sort -nk2)` -- this works great but merges two outputs together on same line, producing left side repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ps -ef | awk '{ print $1 }' | while IFS= read a_pid ; do echo "" ; ps -p $a_pid ; lsof -p $a_pid ; done
```

Comment: awk may be printing the wrong field. adjust depending on the output of your version of ps. Should be $1 or $2

Comment: `man ps` for more options depending on what you need to see (`-o pid,ppid,somethingelse,etime,...` will usually allow you to get a tailored output)(here again, depending on your os, many differences. if `ps -ef` is not good, try `ps -aux`, or read the `man ps`)

Comment: Yep, for me just had to change `$1` to `$2`

Comment: Some (?) versions of `ps` print a header line, and you'll need the `--no-headers` option for the first invocation (the one that's piped into `awk`)